# @Id field not seen if it's in superclass?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

i've a base class that provide only identification:

```
    public abstract class Identifable<T> {
    @Id
    private T id = null;

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean hasId() {
        return id != null;
    }
}
```

and several subclasses that extends it like:

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class MyEntity extends Identifable<String> {
    /* some specific attributes and methods */
}
```

I get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Id field 'id' in com.mypkg.MyEntity must be of type Long, long, or String`.

Why? Can't Objectify see the inherited `@Id` field?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause:

Objectify only inspects types at runtime using reflection. Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) all unbounded type parameters are during compilation converted to `Object` type, which is what objectify sees and complains.

The solution:

Use concrete type for `id` field. Possibly move it to a child class, as proposed by @Anthony.

Answer (score 2):

In JPA, you must use for a field marked with `@Id` one of the following types:
any Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; java.lang.String; java.util.Date; java.sql.Date; java.math.BigDecimal; java.math.BigInteger

Just remove the generics from the base class and use one of the mentioned types for your id field.

Comment: Actually Alfredo, while the annotations surely looks the same, the op is using [objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/)

Comment: From objectify [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities): 

The @Id field can be of type Long, long, or String. If you use Long and save an entity with a null id,
a numeric value will be generated for you using the standard GAE allocator for this kind. If you use
String or the primitive long type, values will never be autogenerated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's reason about if for a while... You are trying to build a super type in which the type of the ID varies. Are you sure that this is what you want objectify to build (a hierarchy of objects in which the root entity has a unknown ID type)? While I've seen this kind of code in several ORM frameworks, this is how I would build what you want.

Interface (not part of the object hierarchy):

```
public interface Identifable<T> {
    public T getId();
    public void setId(T id);
    public boolean hasId(); 
}
```

Root of your hiearchy implements Identifable with a concrete type for the id:

```
@Entity
public class MyBaseClass implements Identifable<String> {
    @Id
    private String id = null;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean hasId() {
        return id != null;
    }
}
```

And subclass comes naturally out of it:

```
@EntitySubclass(index=true)
public class MyEntity extends MyBaseClass {
   // fields, accessors and mutators
}
```